# LuaLatex with VS Code + Local Lua Debugger: Breakpoints ignored in lua scripts that lie in parent folder

Tags: luatex, debugging, lua, vscode

**In short:** When debugging my lualatex files in VS Code with Local Lua Debugger, breakpoints in lua files are ignored if they lie outside the current working directory; for example, if they lie in the parent folder of the file to be compiled.

I successfully set up Visual Studio Code with all the required extensions as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295539/is-there-a-way-to-step-through-lualatex-macros-using-a-remote-debugger) to be able to debug lualatex code.

My setting: I have a folder that I opened in VS Code.
It contains the following three files:

- 'script.lua'
- 'latex/main.tex' *(that is, 'main.tex' is lying in a subfolder called 'latex')*
- .vscode/launch.json *(the configuration file for the debugger)*

script.lua (the content is not relevant for the issue):

```lua
    for i=1,10 do
        tex.print("Hello ")
    end
```

main.tex:

```latex
    % !TeX program = lualatex
    \documentclass{article}
    
    \directlua{%
    if os.getenv("LOCAL_LUA_DEBUGGER_VSCODE") == "1" then
        package.loaded["lldebugger"] = assert(loadfile(os.getenv("LOCAL_LUA_DEBUGGER_FILEPATH")))()
        require("lldebugger").start()
    end}
    
    \begin{document}
    \directlua{require("../script.lua")}
    \end{document}
```

launch.json:

```json
    {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Debug Custom Lua Environment",
                "type": "lua-local",
                "request": "launch",
                "stopOnEntry": false,
                "program": {
                    "command": "lualatex"
                },
                "args": ["${file}"],
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            }
        ]
      }
```

**Issue:** When I put a breakpoint into script.lua (e.g., 2nd line), and
press F5 (when main.tex is selected), then main.tex is compiled without errors, but the breakpoint is ignored.

Can I tell VS Code + Local Lua Debugger to pause at the breakpoints? Important: I want to keep the files where they are and I also do not want to change the path of script.lua in main.tex.

**Observation 1**:
The debugger correctly pauses at the breakpoint, when I change the penultimate line of main.tex to `\directlua{require("script.lua")}` and either

- remove `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"` from launch.json, or
- move script.lua into the folder latex.

**Observation 2**:

- The breakpoints work fine if the file in `require( )` is given by an absolute path, e.g., `require("c:/test/script.lua")`.
- The breakpoints are ignored if the path is relative (to main.tex), e.g. `require("..\script.lua")`.

**But** as noted above, I look for a different solution than the ones of the observations. The reasons: On one hand, I have many files where I would need to carefully update the paths. The path structure is actually more complicated and I want to keep it relative to the respective tex files. On the other hand, I want to be able to compile the files directly from within their directories also without (using the configuration files of) VS Code, e.g., by just using the terminal.

If possible, I would prefer a solution where I have only to configure Local Lua Debugger in an appropriate way without changing the code at all.

**Some ideas:**
The [description page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tomblind.local-lua-debugger-vscode) of Local Lua Debugger mentions two options for the configuration file that sounded promising: `scriptRoots` and `scriptFiles`. However, I was not able to resolve the issue by using them. Maybe I used them wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following, though not fully satisfactional, solution:

1. Write the following code in the header of `main.tex` within a `\begin{luacode}...\end{luacode}` environment (provided by the package `luacode`), or even better in a separate file, say `debug.lua`:

```lua
        if os.getenv("LOCAL_LUA_DEBUGGER_VSCODE") == "1" then
            package.loaded["lldebugger"] = assert(loadfile(os.getenv("LOCAL_LUA_DEBUGGER_FILEPATH")))()
            require("lldebugger").start()
        end
        
        ------------------------------------------------- 
        -- Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42417/full-path-of-current-file
        
        require 'lfs'
        
        function buildPath(...)
            local pathseparator = package.config:sub(1,1)
            local elements = {...}
            return table.concat(elements, pathseparator)
        end
        
        -- get the current path plus the file name.
        function getAbsolutePath(filename)
            return buildPath(lfs.currentdir(), filename)
        end
        -------------------------------------------------
        
        function requireFix(filename)
            return require(getAbsolutePath(filename))
        end
```

2. In `main.tex`, replace `require(filename)` by `requireFixed(filename)` (after `debug.lua` has been included). The new `main.tex` file:

```latex
    % !TeX program = lualatex
    \documentclass{article}
    
    \directlua{require("debug.lua")}
    
    \begin{document}
    \directlua{requireFixed("../script.lua")}
    \end{document}
```

Now everything works fine: VS Code pauses at all the breakpoints, and `main.tex` can be also compiled directly from the terminal.

**Why not fully satisfactional?**
The reason why the solution is not fully satisfactionally is that `main.tex` has been slightly changed. I would prefer a solution where I just set up Local Lua Debugger appropriately without changing the code at all. But, all in all, the solution is good enough for me.

**Background:**
As observed in the question, the breakpoints work if the path to `script.lua` given in `require( )` is absolute (starts with the disc's letter).
The idea is now to wrap a lua function around the (relative) path that I to pass to `require( )` that transforms the relative path into the corresponding absolute path, that is, I write `require(getAbsolutePath("..\script.lua"))`.

Such a lua function was proposed in Paulo Cereda's answer to the question [Full path of current file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42417/full-path-of-current-file). I used it in my solution.